# Cannot read XML file with ReadXml Dataset Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dataset, filenotfoundexception

I have the following method:

```
public static DataSet BringProducts()
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    var dir = @"ProductsCookieData.xml";
    if (File.Exists(dir))    //without File.Exists, same problem.
    {
        dataSet.ReadXml(dir);
    }
    return dataSet;
}
```

The file exists but the method does not see it ever. The file is in C:\, I tried in other locations and the same happens. Also tried without using static.

If I don't use the `File.Exists()`, FileNotFoundException is throwing.

Comment: If `FileNotFound` is thrown, then the file does not exist where you thought it is. Is this ASP.Net or Windows Application?

Comment: It is an ASP.net webform with C# code behind

Comment: Have you tried to create a FileStream on the file and pass the reference of the stream to readxml? Also could you try to pass the absolute path of the file to the dataSet.ReadXml()-call?

Comment: Do you have access to C:\? In which folder is your webapplication located?

Comment: @Aschratt with FileStream same happens, the file is not found. string dir = @"C:\ProductsCookieData.xml";
            FileStream fileName = new FileStream(dir, FileMode.Open);

Comment: @codingbiz I dont know if I have access to C:\, but I put it in other paths and same occurs.

Comment: Please make sure your ASP.NET Application Pool has access to C:\. Be aware that this can be an security risk!

Comment: @Aschratt how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you declared the file

```
var dir = @"ProductsCookieData.xml";
```

Your file has to be in the same directory as your code/current webpage and not in C:. You can give permission to C:\ and change your code to

```
var dir = @"C:\ProductsCookieData.xml";
```

Sometimes, the file can be copied to your application folder, root or special folder and accessed with Server.MapPath

```
var dir = Server.MapPath("~/ProductsCookieData.xml");
```

Comment: Nope, server.mappath did not find it. dont know what to do. Two hours with this error :(

Comment: `Server.MapPath` won't find it if not in your web application folder hierarchy. It won't go outside your web application directory

Comment: I put it everywhere, inside app folder, outside, etc.

Comment: I take out File.Exist(), using Server.MapPath, and finally he found it. Thanks all

Comment: put it in the same folder where you have your `web.config` and try `var dir = Server.MapPath("~/ProductsCookieData.xml");`. Also check the file name speclling or even copy the name from directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full path to the file. Currently, you're only providing a relative path, which will be resolved relative to the current working directory.

If your file is in the root of C:\, then change your code to:

```
string dir = @"C:\ProductsCookieData.xml";
```